# How is Windows 8/8.1 Start Screen made?

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have to make a control and Windows 8/8.1's start screen matches the requirements which is dragging and dropping from one column to another, renaming the columns, etc.

So, I am asking experienced minds here how the screen was made maybe *Hub* coupled with *HubSection*. I do not know so, please suggest on what to get started with. Currently, I have managed to replicate it using `GridView` as the columns and inside it another `GridView` containing the tiles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create default probject called "Grid App" (VS2013). You'll find a grouped `GridView` with headers inside. So you don't need any additional `GridView`. It will looks like this:

```
<GridView
        x:Name="itemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        Padding="60,100,40,20"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedItemsViewSource}}"
        SelectionMode="None"
        IsSwipeEnabled="false"
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">

        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemsPanel>

        <GridView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="5,0,15,5">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Comment: Thanks but your XAML seems to be incomplete. Please provide the complete code.

Comment: I told you how to get it. Create new app in Visual Studio and select template "Grid App".